# $X \times Y \sim Y \times X$, as sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that $X \times Y \sim Y \times X$, as sets, meaning that there exists some bijection between the two. I'm having trouble defining what exactly this bijection should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Map $(x,y)\in X \times Y$ to $(y,x) \in Y \times X$

Comment: How exactly would I show that this function is injective and surjective?

Comment: Injective:  $(x_1,y_1)\mapsto(y_1,x_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)\mapsto(y_2,x_2)$, so if $(x_1,y_1)\mapsto(y,x)$ and $(x_2,y_2)\mapsto(y,x)$ then $(y,x)=(y_1,x_1)=(y_2,x_2),$ which means $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$, which means $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$

Comment: Surjective:  if $(y,x)\in Y\times X$, then $y\in Y$ and $x\in X$ so $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ and $(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$

Comment: To show bijectiveness of $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$, simply show that this map has an inverse, which is obviously $(y,x) \mapsto (x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: @Crostul In fact, the map is its own inverse; we say it's an *involution*. This also makes it surjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bijection between two sets $A$ and $B$, is a function $f:A\to B$  such that$$\forall x\in A\ \ \ ,\ \ \ y\in B\quad :\quad f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$$In your case, one such bijection can be $$f\Big((x,y)\Big)=(y,x)$$

Comment: And treat the "empty product" separately.

Answer (score 2):

A bijection is merely a 1-1 correspondence between elements of the two sets. In other words, if you can pair up each element of $X\times Y$ with exactly one element of $Y\times X$ "with no leftovers" then you have a bijection.

With this intuition in mind, it should be easy to notice that the map $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$ (with $x\in X, y\in Y$) is a bijection $X\times Y\to Y\times X$. If you want to show this formally, you can go back to the definition of an injective and surjective function---but once you understand why this map is bijective intuitively, this is going to be easy.